# Sigmoid function different result from Matlab

Tags: machine-learning

How to code a sigmoid function in Java?, my output for `hx = [0.51,0.51,0.51,0.51,0.51]` is `sigmoid =[1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6]` and when I do it in Matlab the value of sigmoid is `[ 0.6248 ,0.6248, 0.6248, 0.6248]`:

```
public double[] sigmoidFunction() {
    int i;
    double[] sigmoid = new double[x_theta.length];
    for(i=0;i<x_theta.length; i++)
        sigmoid[i] = 1 / 1 + StrictMath.exp(-x_theta[i]);

    return sigmoid;
}
```

Comment: i figure it out, sigmoid[i] = 1 / 1 + StrictMath.exp(-x_theta[i]); should be
sigmoid[i] = 1 / (1 + StrictMath.exp(-x_theta[i]);

Comment: You don't need StrictMath, almost surely. Go back to Math if you were just trying it to get reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about parenthesis:

```
sigmoid[i] = 1 / 1 + StrictMath.exp(-x_theta[i]);
```

is equivalent to

```
sigmoid[i] = (1 / 1) + StrictMath.exp(-x_theta[i]);
```

and so

```
sigmoid[i] = 1 + StrictMath.exp(-x_theta[i]);
```

while you seem to need

```
sigmoid[i] = 1 / ( 1 + StrictMath.exp(-x_theta[i]) );
```